# Qt QMainWindow central widget deletion

Tags: c++, qt

my application requires the user to switch between several screens. The way I'm doing this is by creating different QFrames for each screen, and then setting the Qframes as central widgets on the MainWindow. The problem is that every time I call setCentralWidget(frame), the old frame gets deleted and I can't access it later. How can save that old frame so that I can access it later?

Please let me know if I am unclear in my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove your central widget from `QMainWidow` reparenting it. Then, you could set new centralWidget;

```
QWidget* savedWidget = mainWnd->centralWidget();
savedWidget->setParent(0);//now it is saved
mainWnd->setCentralWidget(newWidget);
```

Also using `QStackedWidget` possibly would be better solution.

Comment: This solution is not working, looking at the QMainWindow  it shouldn't work. Which version of Qt are you using ?

Comment: @Kamath, back in '13 I was probably using Qt 4.8. I haven't been developing using Qt for a while and can not tell, if it should or not work with current versions, but I don't see any reason for object model to change that significantly to break this behaviour

Comment: This is not the exact brach my source for qmainwindow is same as that I have  https://github.com/openwebos/qt/blob/master/src/gui/widgets/qmainwindow.cpp, I see setCurrentWidget calls deleteLater if updated.

Comment: @Kamath, It is probably getting deleted from the layout when you reparent it. That is why `savedWidget->setParent(0);` step is there

Answer (score 4):

QStackedWidget is an elegant solution for this problem, you can find out how to use it properly [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Archived%3aCreate_a_page_based_UI_with_QStackedWidget_and_QToolbar).

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with .hide()/.show() on the appropriate subwidgets to accomplish this. But a better solution for your case is almost certainly to use a [QTabWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html) or [QStackedWidget](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html).